# How I stop the While loop after the 3rd invalid attempt?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

So I have a big problem about stop looping. The main problem is I have to stop the while looping after user input invalid 3 times. However, I don't know how to do that.

How I can stop the while looping after 3rd invalid attempt?

And What code that I should use?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalculatePay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        String Name = " ";
        int hours;
        double payRate;
        char F;
        char P;
        char T;
        char repeat;
        String input = " ";

        double grossPay;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        Name = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("How many hours did you work? ");
        hours = reader.nextInt();
       while (hours < 0 || hours > 280) 
    {
            System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
            hours = reader.nextInt();
          attempt++;
         if(attempt == 3)
         System.out.println("You are Fired!");

          {
             return;
          }

        }
        System.out.print("What is your pay rate? ");
        payRate = reader.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What type of employee are you? ");
        F = reader.next().charAt(0);


        grossPay = hours * payRate;
        DecimalFormat decFor = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        switch (F){
            // irrelevant for the question
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Adam suggested, you'll need a counter, such as:

```
    int attempt = 0;
    while (hours < 0 || hours > 280) {
        System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
        hours = reader.nextInt();
        attempt++;

        // do something if you reach the limit. The >= comparison is 
        // useless before attempt will never go over 4.
        if(attempt == 3){
            // notify the user that something wrong happened
            System.out.println("Your error message here");

            // exit the main function, further code is not processed
            return;
        }
    }
```

I suggested a message print and returning. For your information, other options can be:

- throw an exception with `throw new MaxAttemptReachedException();`
- exit the while loop but keep processing the following code with the `break;` instruction.

Comment: So after 3rd tried, the program should print out "You're Fired". How should I do that?

Comment: Just replace the error message by the message you want and then use `return;` to exit the main function. Answer is updated following your comment

Comment: It said terminated but still not print out the "you are fired!"        while (hours < 0 || hours > 280) 
        {
                System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
                hours = reader.nextInt();
              attempt++;
             if(attempt == 3)
             System.out.println("You are Fired!");
             
              {
                 return;

Comment: I tested my code (Java SE) and it's working fine. You may have an error somewhere. I see in your comment that `return` is after the *if bracket*. In my answer, the return is inside my *if bracket*

Comment: if it's working, please accept / upvote the appropriate answer so that one can know that question is closed

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming this is what you want to do...

```
int attempt = 0;
while (hours < 0 || hours > 280) 
{
        System.out.println("That's not possible, try again!");
        hours = reader.nextInt();
      attempt++;
     if(attempt >= 3)
      {
         break;
      }

    }
```

Comment: As the input is supposed to be incorrect, OP may want to exit the whole function, not simply break the loop. With `break`, the code keeps running afterward which is not the expected behaviour. Unrelated but if I may, please be careful about formatting when posting an answer

Comment: So after 3rd tried, the program should print out "You're Fired". How should I do that?